# In c++, how can I retrieve the values from a vector in the same order they would be retrieved from a map?

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, vector

I'm writing a code that stores objects into a `map<string, vector<T> >`. This map is iteratively filled with data, that data is analyzed, and then written to file in a big loop. Before that loop, I open the file to write out what each column will be, e.g., `# time var1 var2 var3`. The problem is, I need to reliably write `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` etc... in the header in the same order they will be retrieved from the map. I'm using an ugly workaround now, with a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> header_names;
header_names.push_back("var1");
header_names.push_back("var2");
header_names.push_back("var3");
std::map<std::string, std::string> headers;
for(int i = 0; i < header_names.size(); i++) {
    headers[header_names[i]] = header_names[i];
}
std::ofstream outputfile("out.txt");
outputfile << "# time ";
for(auto it = headers.begin(); it != headers.end(); ++it) {
    outputfile << it->first << " ";
}
```

Is there a better way of achieving the same result?

EDIT:

Using @Claudiu's answer, where I initialize the map, and then clear the `vector`s that are the values at the beginning of the big loop.

Comment: Can't you just sort the vector then output in order from beginning to end?

Comment: Where do `var1`, etc. come from?  Are the the keys in the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not iterate through the map itself? That will guarantee you retrieve it in the same order as the map itself because it is the order of the map itself:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<T> > m = ...;

for (const auto& item : m)
{
    outputfile << item.first << " ";
}
```

[Ideone example](https://ideone.com/cHxKSj).

Comment: That's a good idea. I can then clear the `map` at the beginning of the big loop.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::map` sorts its entries by key, using `std::less` (or a custom comparator if you specify one as a template parameter).  If you want to put the entries in a `std::vector` into the same order that they'd be in a map, just use `std::sort` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you wanted to do but here is my advice:

First of all it would be better to write your own small class (or struct if you want) as the container of the variables, something like this:

```
class Variable final
{
public:
    int variable1;
    int variable2;
    int variable3;
};
```

And then you should write a container with the desired helper functions.

```
class Variables final
{
public:
    void add( const Variable& variable )
    {
        data.push_back( variable );
    }

    void write( const std::string& filename )
    {
        std::ofstream outputfile( filename );
        // Write the header texts. This is always the same.
        writeHeader( outputfile );

        // Write the data in a loop.
        writeData( outputfile );
    }

private:
        void writeHeader( std::ofstream& file ) { ... }
        void writeData( std::ofstream& file ) { ... }

private:
    std::list< Variable > data;
};
```